# repeated measures anova in Matlab, F-value interpretation

Tags: matlab, anova

I am using this package for repeated measures anova for [MATLAB](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22088-repeated-measures-anova).

However, I am not sure about the interpretation, and the code is not entirely documented. Say I have one group of people, and measurements from three timepoints (conditions) of those, hence a repeated measures ANOVA with 3 factors. Now I want to see, if there is a significant effect of condition - which F-value corresponds to this question? I would have said the one corresponding to the row "time", but for an $F_2,24$ the F-value on the row "Subject" which is around 12 should be what the F-table lists?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the F for time should be the effect of interest, since you are not interested in differences between subjects. F = 20.82 then. You have 3 time points and 2 degrees of freedom. In order to interpret the effect you should see which time point is different than the others.

Comment: Thank you, this is nevertheless written as F_2,24 - 2 indicating df for condition, and 24 for subjects?